# How to fetch real time webdriver execution logs

Tags: logging, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, log4j, jenkins-plugins

I am executing the Selenium Webdriver scripts in Jenkins. By using log4j, logs are generated in Jenkins console.

When a build is triggered, the live and actual logs from every single line of execution should be logged in console. Each and every action should monitor and produce the log. Can I have these logs generated in UI as it is in Jenkins Console log? At least logs generated in cmd is also good.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question. While a job is running, anything that is sent to `stdout` and `stderr` (so, any output) by a process which is spawned by the job, will be displayed in Jenkin's console log.

You can view the up-to-date console log with the following URL:
`http://<jenkinsurl>/job/<jobname>/lastBuild/logText/progressiveText?start=0`

You can change `lastBuild` to `<runnumber>` of any previous run.

Comment: I am not trying achieve through jenkins. I am achieving from my local machine using my own code. Kindly suggest few API which can help on this.

Comment: Is your machine the one that runs Jenkis? If no, how do you plan to get those logs (e.g. SFTP, HTTP, ...)? Have you considered using an existing remote logs monitor tool? (e.g. LogMX)

Comment: Well, this isn't what you are really asking for, but you can use Jenkins to execute `tail -F filename.log` on remote server, and then watch Jenkins console log for realtime(ish) updates of filename.log :)